# No such property: V for class:

Tags: python, graph, titan, gremlin, tinkerpop3

I'm trying to to use newest OGM named [goblin](https://github.com/ZEROFAIL/goblin).
I read examples and basically i just want to exec a simple query:
MyVertex.all() which should return all vertex of "myvertex" type, but i get

```
No such property: V for class: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.GraphTraversalSource
```

Here is what I'm doing:

```
import asyncio
from tornado.platform.asyncio import AsyncIOMainLoop
from goblin import properties, connection
from goblin.models import Vertex

@asyncio.coroutine
def find():
    result = yield from MyVertex.all()
    stream = yield from result.read()
    return stream

find()
```

Comment: What version of Titan are you running against? Typically, I've seen that error when trying to run TinkerPop 2 compatible queries from goblin. Note that goblin is TinkerPop 3 compatible. It would also be helpful for you to post the code for your MyVertex class here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks god its working, problem was i needed to checkout from dev branch, because of Unbelievable supa-freshnes of this project.